# creating Matlab cell arrays in python

Tags: python, matlab, scipy

I'm trying to create a Matlab cell array in python and save it as a .mat file, but am running into problems when all the cells contain 2 values:

```
import scipy.io as sio

twoValues = {'a': array([[array([[2, 2]]), array([[3, 3]])]])}
sio.savemat('test.mat',twoValues)
```

In Matlab:

```
load('test.mat')
>>> a

a(:,:,1,1) =

           2           3


a(:,:,1,2) =

           2           3


>>> class(a)

ans =

int32
```

Back in python:

```
threeValues = {'a': array([[array([[2, 2, 2]]), array([[3, 3]])]])}
sio.savemat('test.mat',threeValues)
```

In Matlab:

```
>>> a

a = 

    [3x1 int32]    [2x1 int32]


>>> class(a)

ans =

cell
```

What's the reason for this?

Comment: `array()` is trying to pack your values in the most efficient way possible, because you're not specifying `dtype`, and it has to guess at how to store it. When your dimensions match, a plain matrix is evidently the preference. I am so far unsuccessful at coercing it into a cell array when the dimensions match up.

Comment: @CaptainMurphy As you can see in my answer, you have to make an array with `dtype=object`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you do this:

```
a = np.array([[np.array([[2, 2]]), np.array([[3, 3]])]])
```

the final call to `np.array` actually concatenates the inner two, so you get one array at the end:

```
>>> a
array([[[[2, 2]],

        [[3, 3]]]])

>>> a.shape
(1, 2, 1, 2)
```

But to mimic a [cell array](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/create-a-cell-array.html) you want to basically have an array of arrays.  You can acheive this by setting `dtype=object`, but you must create the array and set the elements separately to avoid the automatic merging.

```
three = array([[array([[2, 2, 2]]), array([[3, 3]])]])
two = np.empty(three.shape, dtype=object)
two[0,0,0] = np.array([[2,2]])
two[0,1,0] = np.array([[3,3]])
```

Then:

```
sio.savemat('two.mat', {'two': two})
```

to see what they look like:

```
>>> two
array([[[array([[2, 2]])],
        [array([[3, 3]])]]], dtype=object)

>>> two.shape
(1, 2, 1)
```

Note that I may have gotten confused about your desired shape, since you have so many nested brackets, so you might have to reshape some of this, but the idea should hold regardless.