# Convert Python numpy array to specific Matlab format

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, matlab-struct

I am trying to convert python data to matlab format. It is saving a matlab file that has a data_array of 3x7x5 double.

But I need a file with 1x3 Cell (matlab cell) and in each cell 7x5 double matrix should be there.  I tried to create list of dictionaries using these array and than save to matlab format. But that didn't helped too.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.io
mat1 = np.random.randint(1,100,35).reshape(7,5)
mat2 = mat1*10
mat3 = mat1*0.1
list_mat = [mat1, mat2, mat3]
scipy.io.savemat("test_py1.mat", {'dict_array': list_mat})
```

Description of sample matlab file;
`sample_mat = scipy.io.loadma('sample_mat.mat')`
`type(sample_mat)` => dic
`var1 = sample_mat['key']`
`type(var1)` => numpy.ndarray
`var1.shape = 1 x a`
`var2 = var1[0,0]`
`type(var2)` => numpy.ndarray
`var2.shape = m x n`

Comment: It may be easier to create sample in MATLAB, and save it.  Then look at the `loadmat` result, and try to replicate that.  A numeric `numpy` array translates to a MATLAB matrix, though possibly with a change in `order` (and `order F` might be best).  `cell` and `struct` convert to some mix of `structured array` and object dtype.

Comment: You might find [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19797822/2476977) to be helpful.

Comment: Thanks, I went through sample matlab file in python. I got a dictionary by `loadmat`. dictionary['key'] = numpy.ndarray with shape 1 x m.  Under this numpy array there are 20 numpy.ndarray with shape a x b. But when I am trying the same with my numpy array, it is saving variable in m x a x b shape. I have added the description of sample file in my que too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that the following will work.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.io
mat1 = np.random.randint(1,100,35).reshape(7,5)
mat2 = mat1*10
mat3 = mat1*0.1
list_mat = np.empty(3,dtype = object)
list_mat[0] = mat1
list_mat[1] = mat2
list_mat[2] = mat3
scipy.io.savemat("test_py1.mat", {'dict_array': list_mat})
```

Comment: Thanks, sorry it is not giving the desired solution. It is saving all under 3 x 7 x 5 cell. But I need to save a 1 x 3 cell and under these 3 cells there should be 7 x 5 array

Comment: @abhishek Thanks for checking and thanks for the information; I wasn't able to check with Matlab when I wrote my answer. I'll try to come up with another approach

Comment: @abhishek See my latest edit; I'd appreciate it if you could give it a try and let me know whether it works

Comment: Yes, I was looking for this. Tried with actual problem and It is working fine. Thanks.

Comment: @abhishek Glad to hear it! You're welcome